# .net How to measure time taken to download just the httpPost body excluding httpPost headers and upload data

Tags: .net, performance, response, http-post

One HTTP POST request/response transaction consists of

> 1. Upload Request Ηeaders
> 2. Upload Request Βody
> 3. Download Response Headers
> 4. Download **Response Body**

I'm looking in .net to **measure the time it takes for no 4 above (response body) alone**.
Is there an event sink or clever use of .net api (marking that the POST headers have finished downloading) that I can use to start timing the subsequent response body?

The higher level .net network mechanism suggested for this the better would be i.e. *WebClient*. But any effective .net coding solution would be accepted as well.

Answer (score 0):

This might be somewhere to start..

[DownloadProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged(VS.95).aspx) (when it fires)

and

[DownloadStringCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringcompleted(VS.95).aspx) (when finished)

Comment: Breakpointing in DownloadProgressChanged shows that it fires unreliably either too early before the headers have downloaded (e.TotalBytesToReceive == 0) or too late (e.BytesReceived > 0).